# Is it good to publish our apps without asking Run Time Permission By Targeting sdk to 22

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I found our apps runs even without asking permission like camera, location by setting the Target SDK 22 in API 24,25,26. Is it good to do that? Or we should make our app to ask permission to use Camera, Location of device?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to check and ask permissions mainly because user can remove permissions manualy. In such case, your application could stop working. Handling permissions "in state of art" can avoid useless problems.